# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when using "CountA" to loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet-function

EDIT: Problems was that some of the inputs were strings instead of numbers, this cause this line of code to display the error:

```
CompaniesListBox.List(i - 1, j - 1) = Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value * 100 & " %"
```

EDIT END.

I'm getting a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when i'm trying to run my code.

Basically what i'm trying to do is populate a listbox wihtin a userform with a matrix. I also want to calculate how many rows it should use, (using the wooksheetfunction.CountA) but i get an error which I seem not able to solve.

Any ideas?

after some debugging it seems to be the function that is causing the problem, Maybe "Rows" in not a valid variable for the loop?

```
Private Sub UpdateCompaniesListBox()
    Dim Rows As Integer
    Dim Columns As Integer
    Dim Start As Range
    Dim CountWindowA As Range
    
    
    Set CountWindowA = Sheets("Basic Data").Range("AM4:AM33") 'Window where from top to bottom wheras value can be
    Set Start = Sheets("Basic Data").Range("AM4") ' This should be the first cell that has a value.
    
    Rows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(CountWindowA)
    'MsgBox Rows
    
    Columns = 8

        For i = 1 To Rows
            CompaniesListBox.AddItem
            For j = 1 To Columns
                If (j = 6) Or (j = 7) Then
                    CompaniesListBox.List(i - 1, j - 1) = Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value * 100 & " %"
                    Else
                    CompaniesListBox.List(i - 1, j - 1) = Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    CompaniesListBox.ColumnWidths = "118, 72, 49, 60, 71, 99, 38, 73"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it actually the line `Rows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(CountWindowA)` that throws the error? What line is flagged if you hit Debug?

Comment: I don't get to press the 'debug'.

Comment: Changing the code to this "Rows = 4 'WorksheetFunction.CountA(CountWindowA)" solves the problem, that is why I believe that line throws the error. @BigBen

Comment: I bet the real issue is `Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value * 100 & " %"`. Probably attempting to multiply text by a number.

Comment: After testing, yes you are correct. 
But using a fixed value instead of the CountA function works @BigBen

Comment: Embarrassing, the problem was text in the input data, not any problem in the code. Thank you @BigBen

Comment: `IsNumeric` might be helpful now or in the future.

Comment: As an aside, be very careful creating variables called `Rows` and `Columns` etc. - you've declared them so you're getting away with it but you might want to consider using names that aren't vba keywords as it can cause problems.